# SQLAlchemy not working with versioned SQL table for only certain dates while pyodbc works just fine

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Seems to be working now with no changes being made. I love this job**

When trying to query data from a MSSQL versioned table, SQLAlchemy is failing to pull data for only a certain date range. No errors, just returns a blank table. Using both SSMS and pyodbc, I am able to pull the data for that date range no issue. SQLAlchemy works fine after a certain date but not before which makes no sense to me at all.

Here are some details:

Python 3.10

SQLAlchemy 1.4.44

MS SQL 2019

```
Working Query: SELECT * FROM Table_name FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2022-04-01'
Non-Working Query: SELECT * FROM Table_name FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2022-03-01'
```

And yes there is data for the time range I need to pull.

I tried different drivers for the database connection, different days in the same month, still nothing. Tried with just old pyodbc by itself. Works perfectly despite pandas yelling at me.

Comment: I don’t know alchemy or pandas, but have you tried using a non-regional, unambiguous date string, eg `YYYYMMDD` with no dashes? Or better yet, a proper date(time2) parameter? Also have you checked if you are expecting UTC or local times?

Answer (score 0):

So, this might be deeper than I thought. I tried running it again today with no changes made just to see and now it's working just fine. I just gonna throw the whole computer away.